# How do the interval and lower topologies relate when generated by an arbitrary poset?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

At first glance, it would seem that the lower topology (and the upper topology, for that matter) would be a subset of the interval topology for a partially ordered set P, since the open-ended intervals are the down-sets for a point p.  What complications arise because P is a partial order instead of a total order? Is this the problem? Is it because the interval topology is not built up from down-sets containing incomparable elements? Any non-obvious counterexamples would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Lots.  Interval topology, if we're talking about the same thing, on total order is T5.  On poset it is T1.  This is mentioned at the start of the article* , maybe proofs, if you need them, are in references:

*[SEPARATION AXIOMS FOR INTERVAL TOPOLOGIES](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-079-02/S0002-9939-1980-0565335-8/S0002-9939-1980-0565335-8.pdf)

Comment: TY, I pulled down Erne article and am reading through it.